# MAAS image deployment failed!

Tags: system-installation, maas

I'm trying to setup a MAAS infrastructure, but it seems that it is failing for a reason that I can not pin down at the moment. Maybe someone here can help me out.

All nodes reach the Ready state after commissioning. I've had troubles with that in the beginning but that was because of a hwtime issue, so easy to solve. Then I tried to Acquire and start a node with the fast installer, but the deployment failed with the following error in /var/log/maas/maas.log

```
[ERROR] node1.local: Marking node failed: Failed to get installation result.
```

I actually got 3 of the 4 nodes successfully deployed before. Then I reconfigured the raid set, recommissioned them again, but then maas failed commissioning all the nodes. Not until I formatted the boot partition of each node, I was able to recommission the node to a Ready state.

However, none of the nodes get the fast installer deployment working anymore.

I tried to log in to one of the nodes with ssh ubuntu@node1 to figure out where in the installation process something went wrong, but i'm at a dead end now.

The deployments with the debian installer do work however.

Regards,
Joham

Comment: Doesn't the fast installer image have a limited set of drivers?  i think fast installer is like copying a disk image directly to the disk, as opposed to installing it.  So, if your systems need drivers that are not available in the image, you are SOL.  Does it work when you don't use fast installer?

Comment: yes I believe so. It probably is better suited for KVM images, since that uses a layer of hardware abstraction.